# Can I use plagiarism checker to check the similarity index of my manuscipt?

Tags: publications, ethics, conference, plagiarism, tools

My university provides access to [Turnitin](https://www.turnitin.com/) for every student. I have prepared a manuscript ready for submission to a double-blind review conference for September 2023. Is it OK to use the plagiarism checker to assess the similarity index of my manuscript before submission? Would that be judged as plagiarised work since the review is double-blind?

Comment: Why would you want to do this if you honestly wrote the paper yourself?

Comment: The same page has *"iThenticate ... plagiarism checking tool"* (close to the *"[Similarity](https://www.turnitin.com/products/similarity)"* product). Though the title of the Similarity page starts with *"Plagiarism prevention trusted by educators worldwide"*. Very confusing.

Comment: What tool exactly? *"Similarity"*? *"iThenticate"*? *"[Originality](https://www.turnitin.com/products/originality)"*? Something else?

Comment: I would consider whether Turnitin will store the manuscript, and when a publisher uses Turnitin to check for plagiarism it will find a document that was submitted at your institution that is a 100% match.

Comment: The students at my University also seem to struggle with this concept, and we need to repeatedly explain that plagiarism _is not defined_ by Turnitin score. Case in point: a bewildered student could not understand why they were accused of plagiarism, and as their defence kept on repeating "but my Turnitin score was only 4%!". However, they have lifted _every single figure_ (without attribution) from a published and peer-reviewed piece of work. Since they have tried representing other people's work as their own, this was considered plagiarism _despite_ the low Turnitin score.

Comment: @VitaminE if that were the case, wouldn't issues occur when an article rejected by one publisher is submitted to another journal?

Comment: @FerventHippo As a course instructor in educational use, one can switch off the "upload to the Turnitin repository" facility.  I'm guessing one can do the same as a managing editor in research use.

Comment: @VitaminE and you really want to publish at a place where the publisher then draws the conclusion that the document must be a fake, copied submission instead of realizing what happened?

Comment: @DonQuiKong Not sure what you are asking.  As an editor,  I get a plagiarism report provided by a publisher.   As an editor, it's easier to reject than chasing up to see whether the plagiarised report belongs to an author.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, it's probably not OK: the [Turnitin End User Licence Agreement](https://www.turnitin.com/agreement.asp) says

> You agree to use the Site and Services only as follows:... if You are
> a student, only in connection with a registered class in which You are
> enrolled.

Comment: +1 for having actually read the Terms And Conditions to get to a valid appropriate answer (even if it isn't the kind you'd expect for this kind of question here).

Comment: What if the publication is a result of wrapping up outputs of a module/class into a conference paper? Way back when I was in my MSc, we had a number of academics who were happy to help their students present the projects that were done as part of a course into a publishable paper (we also had some convenient local conferences with student tracks)

Comment: @penelope I think for that level of subtlety, you need to ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 18):

Turnitin is not a tool for checking plagiarism, but for similarity. They are not the same. High similarity does not imply plagiarism. Low similarity does not imply no plagiarism.

Also, if you honestly did all the work yourself, there isn’t any reason to use Turnitin.

Comment: While I agree with what you say, this does not answer the question.

Comment: This is exactly the answer. If you didn't plagiarize you don't need a similarity checker. If you did use it and one of the referees wrongly uses it, you get accused of plagiarism as the text is now in the database. Only texts for which the author has given permission can be submitted, and as noted elsewhere only for classwork.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it OK to use the plagiarism checker to assess the similarity index of my manuscript before submission?

You can do whatever you want with texts you have written yourself. So yes, you may use Turnitin, no problem at all. As others have pointed out, you should know how to interpret the result, of course, and think about the difference between similarity and plagiarism.

> Would that be judged as plagiarised work since the review is double-blind?

I do not get the logic behind this question. Using a tool such as Turnitin does not automatically imply that you plagiarised. And the type of the review process has nothing to do with it, either.

Comment: I suppose the logic is that the tool might remember the paper and then, if the peers check it again, the work will be recognized as something 100% similar to the one stored in the previous check (that was done by the author).

Comment: @Ruslan Particularly since, in a double-blind review process, the referees can't know that the author of the manuscript they're reviewing is the same person who previously submitted something 100% similar to Turnitin.  (Same issue occurs in anonymous grading of undergraduate assignments.)

Comment: "you may use Turnitin, no problem at all." according to one of the other answers, this may be a violation of the Turnitin terms of service.

Answer (score 4):

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism):

> Plagiarism is the fraudulent representation of another person's ... as one's own original work.

So no, "assessing the similarity index of your manuscript" is most certainly not plagiarism.

However, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnitin:

> The essays submitted by students are stored in a database used to check for plagiarism

I'm not sure what exactly Turnitin does with the stored materials, e.g. who can access them. Since your work will be stored there, it can potentially violate the copyright required by your conference. I would check with the conference whether using Turnitin is allowed (and, as others already mentioned, I wouldn't use any such tool in the first place).